# CEFSharp not rendering correctly on client machine

Tags: winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

My Cefsharp application with windows forms is working correctly on my machine and every other machine I tried on except my client's machine, (screen shot below).

I am using winforms to place my cefsharp control

Any idea why this might happen?

[image: Rendering screen shot]

Comment: Does it have an `Intel GPU`? Try disabeling the `GPU`. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/49/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L76

Comment: It works, Thanks alot