# Javascript register Object issue using CefSharp on Client Machine

Tags: c#, cefsharp

We have a desktop application and a web application and we are using cefsharp to notify desktop values to web and web values to desktop by registering a Javascript object which is working fine on each and every machine I have tested but on client machine i'm getting error registering Javascript object.

> ReferenceError: objectForCallingServerSideMethods is not defined
> at HTMLDocument. (LoggedInMessages?LoggedIn=true:100)
> at j (loginjsfiles?v=4x4LEDbznlDngCJ68yz-i3I2T5t7NZ7g-pO8qhoUPGg1:3)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (loginjsfiles?v=4x4LEDbznlDngCJ68yz-i3I2T5t7NZ7g-pO8qhoUPGg1:3)
> at Function.ready (loginjsfiles?v=4x4LEDbznlDngCJ68yz-i3I2T5t7NZ7g-pO8qhoUPGg1:3)
> at HTMLDocument.K (loginjsfiles?v=4x4LEDbznlDngCJ68yz-i3I2T5t7NZ7g-pO8qhoUPGg1:3)

This is the error message I'm receiving on client machine where "objectForCallingServerSideMethods" is my Javascript object.

[Cefsharp didn't start on Client Machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780653/cefsharp-didnt-start-on-client-machine)

[CEFSharp not rendering correctly on client machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320700/cefsharp-not-rendering-correctly-on-client-machine)

These two links didn't help much. But my issue is almost similar to them.

Note: There is no issue in code or logic as our application is working fine on hundreds of client's machines but we are facing issue on our new client machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your original question and provide some additional information. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Questions-&-Support#when-asking-a-question-please-include-the-following

Comment: If you require further assistance then please provide more detail.